# In BPMN, what is the best way to start a sub process from any step in a series of consecutive steps?

Tags: workflow, jbpm, bpmn, camunda, bpmn.io

Consider a simple workflow:

`Start->Step1->Step2->Step3->Step4->Step5->End`

What is the best way to start a subprocess **in parallel** (e.g. send message) optionally from **either one** of the steps between `Step2` to `Step4`? For example, at `Step2`, under certain condition, it could start a subprocess in parallel, and merge back with `Step5`. Then the two parallel flows are:

> ```
> Start->Step1->Step2->Step3->Step4->Step5->End
>             ->Subprocess.........->
> ```

Another example, the subprocess could start from `Step3`, i.e.

> ```
> Start->Step1->Step2->Step3->Step4->Step5->End
>                    ->Subprocess..->
> ```

Or, the subprocess may not start at all, i.e. only this:

> ```
> Start->Step1->Step2->Step3->Step4->Step5->End
> ```

This is a much-simplified case. The real workflow is more complex, involving more tasks, gateways, and even subprocesses between `Step1` to `Step5`. So it seems not a good idea to manually add conditions at every step to start the subprocess.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a scope around the steps during which the parallel operation should be possible by using an embedded sub process. Then you can attach a non-interrupting message event handler to this scope. The event handler then triggers the parallel process.

The same can also be done, within an embedded sub processes or within the parent, with an event-based sub process.

https://docs.camunda.io/docs/components/modeler/bpmn/embedded-subprocesses/

https://docs.camunda.io/docs/components/modeler/bpmn/event-subprocesses/

The synchronization at the last step can be done via a message, signal or conditional event.